# What kind of preposition should I use (in into '_')?

Tags: prepositions

Question:

> Question: What kind of preposition should I use OR each of them is acceptable for different cases?
>
> **IN** or/and **INTO** or/and '**_**'

1. He turned **into** the red color
2. He turned **in** the red color
3. He turned **red**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**He turned red.**

We usually don't say "the red color" when we just mean "red".  Slavic languages tend to do this, as in **красный цвет**.

In some cases, however, we might use it to mean "a particular shade of red":

> When he became angry, he often turned a red color which reminded me of cherry tomatoes.  It usually took five minutes after he'd calmed down before the red color went away.

Note that this isn't **red** in general, but a certain red.

Also, since "turn" is used as a copula verb, we don't need any preposition.  Here are some examples of copula verb sentences, starting with one about color:

> I was afraid to eat the cheese because it had turned greenish-blue.
>
> She was so frightened that she looked white.
>
> When she learned that Bob was now dating Shirley, she became green with envy.

("Green with envy" is a common metaphor.)

> The sky looks dark gray.

Comment: You can, however, say "He turned into the colour red".

Comment: I agree.  If someone actually becomes the color itself, that makes sense.  For example, if there's a myth about three gods and after creating the universe each one becomes a color, then you can say that they turned into the colors pink, purple, and chartreuse (or whatever), just as some myths describe characters turning into astronomical and geographical features.

Comment: @SteveES You can, but it wouldn't make any sense except in the odd case that Epanoui, which isn't really helpful for people who are trying to learn English

Comment: I think that I saw that in a phrasebook once.  "Please get a doctor.  I am turning into the color green.  Please stop taking photographs."

Answer (score 6):

The most common way of phrasing this would be option 3:

> He turned red

1. The phrase **turned into** is usually used to indicate a wholesale
   transformation of something, for example:

   > He turned into a dragon

   or

   > As spring turned into summer ...

   You therefore *can* say **He turned into the colour red**. People
   would *probably* understand what you meant, but it would be an unusual way 
   of phrasing it and people might think that "he" had transformed into an 
   abstract concept, "the colour red". As Epanoui has already said, **the red 
   colour** would not be used in this context, but **the colour red** can be.

   (As a side note, **turned into** can also be used to describe someone who is 
   travelling, to say that they went into a particular place, e.g. "He turned 
   into the driveway". For this case, however, you might want to split up 
   "into" to be "in to" so it doesn't sound like you're saying that they 
   transformed themselves into the driveway...)
2. The phrase **turned in** has a different meaning to the one you
   want. It either means:

   **to go to bed**:

   > He turned in for the night.

   Or **to give something to someone**:

   > He turned in his exam paper.

Comment: The most common usage of "turn in" that I come across (British English) is to turn in a criminal (i.e., take them to the police) and, most often, the police encouraging criminals to "turn themselves in".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yep, absolutely, although I would argue that that has the same meaning as "to give something to someone", just that the "something" is a "someone".

Comment: I agree that it's the same meaning; it just seems to be a more common example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In the US, the example SteveES gives is probably the most common use (school work and tests given to the teacher/professor); I'm just curious, how would that be said in the UK? SteveES, I wonder if there's a nuance of *giving something to someone **in authority***? Other common examples I can think of include *turn in your badge* (e.g. in maverick cop movies), *turn in a found item to the lost-and-found*, *turn in paperwork*, *turn in the hotel key when you check out*, etc.

Comment: @1006a In the UK, it would be more common to "hand in" rather than "turn in" work. I think by definition, "turning/handing in" is to a person/body of authority over the handee.

Comment: "Turn in" can also mean to rotate within a defined space, as in "turn in one's grave," or "turn in a circle."